# Build an ASCII Hotel

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, printable-ascii

Every 3 seconds, add a room to the house.

A house with one room looks like this:

```
|---|
|[=]|
|---|
```

Two rooms:

```
|---||---|
|[=]||[=]|
|---||---|
```

Three rooms:

```
|---|
|[=]|
|---|

|---||---|
|[=]||[=]|
|---||---|
```

Four rooms:

```
|---||---|
|[=]||[=]|
|---||---|
|---||---|
|[=]||[=]|
|---||---|
```

Five rooms:

```
|---||---|
|[=]||[=]|
|---||---|
|---||---||---|
|[=]||[=]||[=]|
|---||---||---|
```

- The rooms have to form a square, or as close as you can get, as shown above.
- You must use stdout or the equivalent

Smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: For the two rooms, could they go on top of each other, since that's just as close to a square as next to each other? (This also applies similarly for larger inputs)

Comment: The order the rooms are added are inconsistent. Does it matter how we add the rooms as long as it forms a square (or as close as possible)?

Comment: Why is there a space between the rows of rooms for 3 rooms, but not for 4 rooms?

Comment: What it does mean to be as close to a square as possible?

Comment: Expanding on @xnor's point, which is squarer for 15, 5x3 perfect rectangle, or 4x4 with the corner missing? Are we allowed to move rooms that have already been drawn? If we're not allowed to move rooms, I'd go for the latter, but it's up to you to specify.